# Only have to enter first word with Recaptcha

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, recaptcha

I'm using Google's Recaptcha control, using [MVC Recaptcha](http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/).  The MVC Recaptcha component wraps the Google Recaptcha control.  For some reason, the control allows the first word to be entered only, but the second word can be missing and incorrect, and this works fine.  Not in all cases, but I have noticed it in one area of the application.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I think that's how ReCaptcha is supposed to work--the first word is known, the second word is one they're trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore

> "The user is then asked to read both words. If they solve the one for
>   which the answer is known, the system assumes their answer is correct
>   for the new one. The system then gives the new image to a number of
>   other people to determine, with higher confidence, whether the
>   original answer was correct."

---

> "Currently, we are helping to digitize old editions of the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/) and books from [Google Books](http://books.google.com/)."

Answer (score 1):

This is normal operation for recaptcha.

It uses one word that it knows for sure what it is and one word which it wants you to translate for it.

The most "everyday" word is normally the one you have to get correct and the weird word you can pretty much type anything in there.

Its looking to build a pool of answers and then out of all the translations given it will pick the most common answer to go in its official translation dictionary.

If you read up on the website you will see that it is part of a digitization project to convert books into electronic versions.